# Should a callback of an async task run subsequent tasks asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Authors of [Node.js Design Patterns](https://www.nodejsdesignpatterns.com/) suggest this code as a sample of an operation that schedules asynchronous tasks from some `queue` array and at once keeps a number of running async tasks below a limit (`concurrency`) (I made the authors example simpler):

```
next () {
 while (running < concurrency && queue.length) {
   const task = queue.shift()
   task(() => {
     running--
     process.nextTick(next)
     })
   running++
   }
 }
```

My misunderstanding is why is following calls of `next()` scheduled through `process.nextTick()` (that is asynchronously)? Why can't a task callback run `next()` immediately (that is synchronously)?

The authors pointed out that in the Node.js world when a task expects a callback as an argument, it always should run it asynchronously to avoid grim repercussions. But it's the other thing, the arrow function doesn't pretend to be an asynchronous task, it's just a callback itself. So is there some compelling rationale an async task callback should schedule subsequent tasks in async manner or it's all the matter of style?

Comment: By definition, "keeps a number of running async tasks below a limit" implies that some of these tasks are going to block.  Does the book explain the purpose for limiting the concurrency in this way, or is it just a technique to achieve a software developer's desired outcome (namely that of limiting concurrency)?  I do agree that limiting concurrency and "always should run it asynchronously to avoid grim repercussions" do seem at odds.

Comment: @Robert Harvey the latter. We just desire to restrict a number of simultaneous async tasks for some reasons. I also have to say (cause it's not obviously can be drawed from my post) the authors mentioned the problem with synchronous running of async tasks in *other* context.

Comment: I think you might be missing a different point: process.nextTick() "runs its callback after the rest of the user's code and before the event loop is allowed to proceed.". So, the difference could be in the order of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall rule here is this: ***"If a callback is EVER called asynchronously through any code path, then it should always be called asynchronously, even if the result or error is known synchronously."***

This is because you NEVER want an API that sometimes calls its callback synchronously and sometimes asynchronous.  That makes it very easy for the caller to end up with hard to find and reproduce bugs that only surface when the API itself sometimes calls things synchronously or sometimes calls them asynchronously or sometimes call it one way the first time and then another way the second time.

Here's an example I've seen in the nodejs streams code.  There is an API in the streams code that accepts an asynchronous callback.  But, as the API starts to process things, it finds that it already has in its buffer the required data to satisfy the API request.  It could call the callback synchronously because it already has the data.  But, other times, it will have to read data from the disk before calling the callback and thus the callback will be called asynchronously.  In the streams code, when it encounters this case where it already synchronously has the data, it still queues the callback to be called on the nextTick because it needs to consistently only return the data asynchronously.

Similarly, sometimes, as part of the setup code for a particular stream API, it encounters an error and that error is known synchronously.  Again, it only calls the callback with the error on a nextTick so that it is again being consistent and always calling the callback asynchronously.

But, don't take this too far as this does not mean that every single callback should only ever be called asynchronously on a future tick.  It's perfectly OK to have a callback that is always called synchronously as long as the API explains that and the caller expects that.  Heck, all the array iteration functions like `.map()` or `.filter()` do exactly that and work just fine for what they do and they are massively simpler to use because of their synchronous nature.

---

In the context of your specific code you show, doing:

```
process.nextTick(next)
```

instead of just

```
next()
```

Keeps you from getting any stack build-up as each call to `next()` will run on its own clean stack frame, even if that callback from the task is called synchronously.  So, a well-behaved `task` that always calls it callback asynchronously wouldn't need this, but this is prevention against the task not behaving that way.

Comment: One might argue that it's the responsibility of the author of the `task` to guarantee the callback is called asynchronously, and not of the queuing code. I would think that the use of `process.nextTick` in `next` is only a precaution for tasks that are *not* well-behaved.

Comment: @Bergi - Fair enough, I originally answered in the abstract about callbacks because they referenced the design pattern link, not in the context of the specific code shown.  I have since added a bit more to my answer about their specific code.